# Deleted Sudo and Can't Access Grub

Tags: boot, root, grub

I deleted sudo, and I can't access grub so that I can restore it. I have a bad feeling that I don't have grub. Is there any possible way to restore it? apt-get doesn't work on my computer either.

Comment: Could you give more details about your system? Why can't you just login as root and restore `sudo` from a root prompt, perhaps by downloading its package manually and installing it with `dpkg`?

Answer (score 0):

You can work it out by `chroot`ing into your Debian/Ubuntu system from any other LiveCD or LiveUSB distribution. Suppose you boot your computer with a Debian LiveCD:

```
# Mount your file systems as specified in your system's fstab
# e.g. into /mnt

# Mount the virtual filesystems before chrooting
for DIR in sys proc dev dev/pts; do mount -o bind $DIR /mnt/$DIR; done

# now chroot into your system
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

From then on just run commands as if you were in a terminal on your initial system. When you're done, run `sync` and reboot into your repaired system.

Note I *think* this might not work as expected if your system uses SELinux. You'll have to try first.

Comment: thanks so much for the help. My computer, however doesn't have a spot to insert a CD.

Comment: May be it has a spot to insert an USB key ?

Comment: @netmonk Oh, do I have to have a certain type of flashdrive?

Comment: just download an iso and burn it on a 4gb usbkey at least and boot on it to fix your computer with the chroot method proposed above.